# Is there a way to deserialize to ExpandoObject and have strong typings after

Tags: c#, typescript, json.net

**Scenario**

- A 3rd party vendor passes in data in JSON format which is stored in DB as a json string
- This data is an array of objects which is completely dynamic ie., the properties could be different from one set of data to another. There can be overlaps, but the structure is assumed to differ at any time
- Eg.,

  [
  {
  "prop1": "100",
  "prop2": "200"
  }, {
  "prop1": "100.5",
  "prop2": "200.5"
  }
  ]

  [ { "prop3": "10",
  "prop4": "20",
  "prop5": "30" },
  { "prop3": "20",
  "prop4": "50",
  "prop5": "100" } ]
- 

**Task in hand**

- This data to be displayed in UI as a table
- If I were to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExpandoObject>>` and pass it along to the UI, I can iterate over this array and construct the html table dynamically. No problem.
- The challenge is that I want to have more control over what columns get deserialized & the ability to override the property names. Since it is all dynamic, I do not see a way to accomplish this.
- On top of this, some columns of this table data can in turn be dynamic (as in the value could change at runtime eg., *latest sale price* which is to be fetched from back-end. This creates a situation where I have to somehow track the columns which are dynamic in UI.

Any ideas ? or suggestions to improve my question for better clarity ? I was thinking of doing some post-processing after the data is deserialized like - change property names etc. Not sure what would be the best approach to this.

Comment: Have you tried using `JToken`, `JArray` and `JObject` from Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: You can deserialize your array into a list of key/value dictionaries (`System.Test.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);`). After that you can perform your logic on this key/value pairs.

Comment: Ok. Will try both the above and see. Thanks